# Creating a function which when called will initialize my serial port(com port)

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

my code goes like this:

```
import serial
ser=serial.Serial(port="COM5",baudrate=57600)
```

thats it..it is the simple code
i want this to be in a function called initPort()

after that i called this in this way
initPort()
but when i started using it..then i am not able to get all its attributes..pls help

```
def initPort(port):
    import serial
    import time
    global ser
    ser=serial.Serial(port,57600,timeout=None)
    return ser
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Akshat Pant/.PyCharmCE2019.1/config/scratches/scratch_31.py", line 136, in <module>
    print(sendCmd(cmdchk))
  File "C:/Users/Akshat Pant/.PyCharmCE2019.1/config/scratches/scratch_31.py", line 128, in sendCmd
    ser.write(serial.to_bytes(b[0:6]))
NameError: name 'serial' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

You should move the import statements back to the top of the file. That way, the serial and time modules will be available globally throughout your program.

Comment: ok sir.. it is done..but in next step i want to use the attributes of this module such as write,read etc..how can i do that?

Comment: You initialise the serial object with `ser = serial.Serial(...)` and then use `ser.write()`. Are you facing any errors here?

Comment: @AkshatPant first test new code with your next step and when you get problem then create new question on new page. You will have more space to code, error message and other information.

Comment: @furas didnt get you sir!!

Comment: @AkshatPant good rule: first try code, later ask. Stackoverflow rule: one page = one question. If you have new question then use button "Ask question" and create new question on new page. You will have more space for text, code, errors, etc.